# rotating UIbutton, while rotating parentview they reside with in

Tags: ios, xcode

I have one UIView that I rotate manually when orientation changes, this UIView hosts a number of buttons, I want to rotate them too based on the change in orientation.

I am doing this :

```
  CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -4);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
    {

        self.parentView.firstButton.transform =   CGAffineTransformConcat(self.parentView.firstButton.transform, rotation);
        self.parentView.secondButton.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.parentView.secondButton.transform, rotation);
        self.parentView.thirdButton.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.parentView.thirdButton.transform, rotation);
        self.parentView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.parentView.transform, rotation);
    }
        completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
    }];
```

parentView does rotate properly, but the other buttons do not !!
do I need to perform the rotation in another call? as in I cannot rotate a button and its parentview in the same block?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to rotate the parentView. Make sure that you assign `self.parentView.transform` first. Try directly assigning a proper transform with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` and do not rely on a current state of the transform property (like using `CGAffineTransformConcat()`). Don't forget to make sure the subviews are really subviews of the parentView - a `[self.parentView addSubview:...]`should occur somewhere. If you use IB to set up subviews this can be tricky; check the view hierarchy tree of IB!